# Удаление из двусвязного списка

Tags: c++

Написал функцию удаления из начала двусвязного списка. Но при удалении происходит ошибка, не могу понять, что она даже значит. 
[image: ошибка]

```
void queue::del()
{
 if (head == NULL)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    if (head == tail)
    {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        queue_elem *temp=head;
        head = head->next;
        head->prev = tail;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к либо уже освобождённой, либо непроинициализированной памяти. Кроме того, вы дали код одной функции, а на скриншоте другая.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите точно тот код где происходит ошибка, а также тексты функций в которых вы инициализаруете список и добавляете в него новые элементы.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Я разобрался. Я там запутался в указателях и в функции вывода он пытался обратиться к непроинициализированной или неосвобожденной, как подсказал мне выше @VladD

Answer (score 3):

Вы делаете проверку на равенство NULL. C++ устроен так, что начальное значение указателя может быть каким угодно.

Проверьте, что у Вас `head` и `tail` в самом начале инициализируются как `NULL`, также, при создании новых объектов, указатели `prev` и `next`. Возможно, в этом кроется вся проблема.